# c++ dll xml documentation comments in c# vs2015

Tags: c#, c++, xml, dll

i have a DLL written in C++ with some calculation functions.
i use PInvoke (Platform Invoke) for using it in C# windows form.
i also have a XML documentation in the DLL folder.
i'm using Win7 x64 and updated VS2015 and x64 compiler in both sides.
**Question:**
why i can't see comments in intelliSense in C#?
here is my C++ code

```
///<summary>this is sample</summary>  
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall foo(int a, int b)
{
    int c = a*a + b*b;
    return c;
}
```

here is my C# code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("Project2")]
        public static extern int foo(int a, int b);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = foo(4, 5).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

the function works fine but i can't see documentation in intelliSense.
thanks.

Comment: I don't see any comments in the c++ code so why would youi expect to see the comments in c#?

Comment: The first line of code is a statement calculating the sum of squares.  No comment.

Comment: If you want to be able to step into the c++ code you need to build the c++ with source code and a map ,otherwise, you will just see the assembly language.

Comment: i don't want see code or comments. i only want to see XML documentation in c#. it is said that if you put XML file with same name with DLL in its folder, intelliSense must load and show them. but i can't see them.

Comment: The c++ and c# would bot need to be compiled with /doc option :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0we08bk.aspx

Comment: @Mokhabadi Did you even found a solution? I have a similar situation. I have a C++ COM object that I'm using in a C# application. Interop.dlls are created and I've created intellisense XML-files, with the same name as the interop dlls. I've placed the XMLs in the same folder but I don't get intellisense in my C# application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late Answer! I write my solution for others if they have same problem.
i found that for C++ PInvoke it is impossible. XML documentation is for .Net compliant codes. I change my solution for that project to C++/CLI. and that was the solution! C++/CLI is .Net compliant and fully support XML documentation. also its referencing is different. you simply add the C++/CLI project to your solution or add its dll to references. C++/CLI in my opinion have some benefits and i think it doesn't have drawbacks in comparison with C++. i don't think it have been possible with PInvoke.
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the XML documentation on the method in your C# code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Does some stuff.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">Helps with stuff.</param>
    /// <param name="b">Also helps with stuff.</param>
    /// <returns>The result of doing stuff.</returns>
    [DllImport("Project2")]
    public static extern int foo(int a, int b);
```

Note that attribute sections are considered part of the method declaration, and as such, the XML documentation must precede these ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments)).